# React Hot Module Replacement with Outlook Add-In?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to use webpack-dev-server and hot module replacement in an outlook web add-in?  My content is loading fine, but changes do not seem to be applying until I close and re-open the task pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my self-signed-cert was not being trusted in chrome due to a missing Subject Alternate Name.  After I straightened that out, I'm at least getting full refreshes, so I assume there's nothing inherent with office web add-in development that will prevent hot module reloading from working correctly.